# core data editor problems

Tags: core-data, editor

I was recommended by someone in Stack Overflow to use Core Data Editor http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/ to manage the sqlite persistent store. However the latest version (3.0) crashes on launch everytime. Older versions load but I see nothing when i point the config to the persistent store and the object model directories. There is no documentation either.

can someone point me to the right place to sort this problem? I am trying to find a more manageable way to coordinate core data development than sqlite consoles.

thank you

Comment: What do you need the console for?  Are you trying to enter data manually?

It would help if you could explain what you are using this tool for so that other suggestions can be offered.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the compiled model in Core Data Editor (ending in .moc, not the .xcdatamodel). You can find it in the resources folder of your app bundle.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so, why not accepting the answer, this way people will respond more to your questions